# Why does bright objects make less bright objects invisible?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, lenses

I was walking by the sidewalk during the night when I noticed a swarm of flies circling a street lamp. It was difficult to see at first, so I tried looking in different angles. The security gate came in by pure chance between me and the streetlight. Now the insects became crystal clear. I tried to capture this in camera, and the same effect can be observed.

[image] [image]

Now the object between me and the streetlight doesn't matter. My umbrella, or even my hand also works.
I would like to know why exactly the blocking of the dominant light source allows the less dominant ones to be seen. The light from the less dominant ones were still present before blocking the light. **What roles does blocking play here?**

Many a times me and my friends have to abandon astrophotography camps in the night due to an overly bright moon or street lamp nearby. **Can this same method be utilized to capture a clear image of stars in the night sky?**

Comment: Uh, it happens because you're blocking the dominant light source so that other less-bright things can be seen? AFAIK, astronomers have been doing this for decades...

Comment: @KyleKanos  I would like to know why exactly the blocking of the dominant light source allows the less dominant ones to be seen. The light from the less dominant ones were still present before blocking the light. What roles does blocking play here?

Comment: @Downvoter and close voter, I honestly do not understand what the problem is with this question. Please comment which part needs more clarity.

Comment: *I would like to know why exactly the blocking of the dominant light source allows the less dominant ones to be seen* Imagine adding 100 numbers together, but one number is a billion while the rest are 10. The sum of these is still about a billion (avg $\sim10^7$). If you remove the billion value, the sum is now 990 (avg =10).

Comment: Automatic gain control (automated exposure) of the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was walking by the sidewalk during the night when I noticed a swarm of flies circling a street lamp...

> I would like to know why exactly the blocking of the dominant light source allows the less dominant ones to be seen.

The street light is emitting a bright light, which is why you can see it.

The insects are reflecting that bright light, which is why you can see them.

If you are at a location $\vec r_0$ and the street light is at a location $\vec r_L$ and one of the insects is at a location $\vec r_I$, then when you block the light from the street light you place a barrier along the direction of:
$$
\vec r_1 = \vec r_L - \vec r_0\;.
$$
You are using a finite size barrier, so you are blocking the light within some finite solid angle about the direction $\vec r_1$.

The insect at $\vec r_I$ is not necessarily within the blocked solid angle about $\vec r_1$, because the direction from you to the insect is
$$
\vec r_2 = \vec r_I - \vec r_0\;,
$$

The angle between $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ is
$$
\theta = \arccos(\frac{\vec r_1\cdot\vec r_2}{|r_1||r_2|})\;.
$$

If $\theta$ is big enough to be outside the solid angle you are blocking with the barrier, then you can see the insect. This is because the light reflected off the insect is not blocked by the barrier and so can make it to your eye/camera.

---

There is also an aspect of light saturation to this question. You don't see the insects when the bright street light is *not* blocked because your field of vision (or your digital camera acquisition screen or your film) is saturated by the bright light.

But, the upshot is that you are blocking the light from the street light, but not the reflected light from the insects.

> **Can this same method be utilized to capture a clear image of stars in the night sky?**

Yes. Or, well, similar methods.